Filter list items with jquery
I want to hide with jquery one of the list-items at the left-bottom of the page on www.weert.nl, for example the one with title 'Kerststal van de zusters Birgittinessen'.
How to do this?
Everyting I've tried, is not working on the list-items.
This is my script:
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Ensure whitespace and case issues are handled
    $('#evenementenlijst li').each(function() {
        // Get the trimmed text of the a element
        const linkText = $(this).find('a').text().trim().toLowerCase();
        // Check if it matches "live music"
        if (linkText === 'kerststal van de zusters birgittinessen') {
            $(this).hide(); // Hide the li element
        }
    });
});

Any sugestions? Thanks in advance!

You're running your code when the page first loads. But that part of the page is updated by JavaScript, so the item you want to remove isn't there yet. You can use a MutationObserver to detect when it's added and remove it.

Thanks! That helps me a lot!

You could make use of the rather new, but well supported, :has CSS pseudo-class to apply display:none to any li element that has a descendent that has the link to the relevant location.
In JavaScript you can do that as follows:
document.head.insertAdjacentHTML(
    "beforeEnd", 
    "<style> li:has(a[href*=birgittinessen]) { display: none; } </style>"
);

This can be executed before the target element is inserted in the DOM.
